# select specific sub content by jquery ajax

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, crash

is it possible to call just the content of an specific element via ajax? may be just the innerhtml of the body element of the called site?

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me as if fancybox will let you provide URLs the same way that the jQuery "load()" routine does. Try changing the line where you set the fancybox href to something like:

```
'href' : jQuery("a", this).attr("href") + ' body',
```

now that may not work exactly because it's still a little weird to put a "body" element directly into any normal content box. I don't know whether fancybox would support:

```
'href' : jQuery("a", this).attr("href") + ' body *',
```

but it might be worth a try.  Alternatively, if you can change the pages that are fetched for those dialogs, you could have each page be wrapped in some sort of `<div>` with a particular "id" or "class" value, and then the selector could look for that.

Comment: Thank you for your try to help. but this won't work. i won't load any content anymore.